# Interesting drink, binary search, codeforces

Tags: python, binary-search

`your text`I am very beginner and I would like to solve this problem by using binary search, and it runs correctly until 5th case, in some variants it shows the answer is x and my output is x-1 for example instead of 475 my code shows 474. It is not time limit exceeded. Something is wrong. Here is the problem:

Vasiliy likes to rest after a hard work, so you may often meet him in some bar nearby. As all programmers do, he loves the famous drink "Beecola", which can be bought in n different shops in the city. It's known that the price of one bottle in the shop i is equal to xi coins.

Vasiliy plans to buy his favorite drink for q consecutive days. He knows, that on the i-th day he will be able to spent mi coins. Now, for each of the days he want to know in how many different shops he can buy a bottle of "Beecola".

Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000) — the number of shops in the city that sell Vasiliy's favourite drink.

The second line contains n integers xi (1 ≤ xi ≤ 100 000) — prices of the bottles of the drink in the i-th shop.

The third line contains a single integer q (1 ≤ q ≤ 100 000) — the number of days Vasiliy plans to buy the drink.

Then follow q lines each containing one integer mi (1 ≤ mi ≤ 109) — the number of coins Vasiliy can spent on the i-th day.

Output
Print q integers. The i-th of them should be equal to the number of shops where Vasiliy will be able to buy a bottle of the drink on the i-th day.

```
right = int(input()) - 1
prices = list(map(int, input().split()))
prices.sort()

for i in range(int(input())):
    n = int(input())
    r = right
    l = 0
    while l<=r:
        mid = (r+l) // 2
        if n > prices[mid]:
            l = mid+1
            mid = (l+r)//2
        elif n < prices[mid]:
            r = mid - 1
            mid = (l+r)//2
        elif n == prices[mid]:
            break
    if prices[mid] <= n:
        print(mid+1)
    elif mid < 0:
        print(0)
    else:
        print(mid)
```

I expected all variants would be good

Comment: If prices are `1 2 3 3 4` and `n == 3` you may end with `mid == 2` and ignore the second shop with price 3.

Comment: also see https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right